# Font-awesome Icon disappearing on change of font

Tags: html, fonts, font-awesome, google-font-api

I'm trying to incorporate *font-awesome* icons in my webpage, and it all works fine, until I change to my font of choice, *Exo 2*, and the icons show up as a bordered square. It works fine with other fonts, but for some reason this won't work.

I have included the *font-awesome* stylesheet, and the google fonts stylesheet.

If anyone could point me to what I'm doing wrong, would be appreciated!

Comment: you must be trying something wrong can u show us the code

Comment: I think i might have an idea, Could it be that instead of calling font ''exo 2'', i should me calling ''fontawesome''?

Comment: yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue with font-awesome could be due to setting other font to the icon. Please see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4f4k2y4L/)

```css
.parent1,
.parent1 > i{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.parent2{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a30dc5ca39.js"></script>
<div class="parent1">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>This won't work
</div>
<div class="parent2">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>This works
</div>
```

If you set the font to the child element i.e. the `<i>` element, then font-awesome won't be rendered as you expect.

In the second example I only set different font to the parent, but not the icon, and it works as expected

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how do i change the font text when i use this: <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"> text goes here </i><br>

Comment: the purpose of `<i clas="fa ..."></i>`, when using font-awesome, is to show icon, not other content. You can place other content in `divs`, `spans` or whatever element that fits your needs, just like I showed you above in the example

Answer (score 1):

fontawesome is font icons and Exo 2 is font and not "font icons"

to work fontawesome u must apply

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
```

and if u change it to something else here i think "Exo 2"

```
font-family: Exo 2;
```

it wont work and will disply u square

Answer (score 0):

i got the same issue and thats how fixed it.

**before**

```
*, *::after, *::before{

   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-family: 'Your Custom Font', sans-serif;
}
```

**After**

```
*{
    font-family: 'Your Custom Font', sans-serif;
}

*, *::after, *::before{

   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```